# MYSQL+PHP: Array Processing?

Tags: php, mysql, records

With this as my base code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `memberlist` WHERE Active = 1";

$res = mysql_query($sql);

if (mysql_num_rows($res) > 0) {
  while ($temp = mysql_fetch_array($res, MYSQL_BOTH)) {
```

What I would like to happen with the results is:

In a do while:

1. Get the first record, do something.
2. Get the first record, do something. Get the second record, do something.
3. Get the first record, do something. Get the second record, do something. Get the third record, do something.
4. Get the first record, do something. Get the second record, do something. Get the third record, do something. Get the fourth record, do something.

... and just keep going until all the records have been processed, and then start back at 1. and just keep repeating the whole process until the while in the do while is satisfied.

Is this too complex?

If I need to clarify, please let me know...

I'd appreciate the help!

Thank you!

Comment: mysql_* functions are deprecated and will be removed from PHP. You should consider to switch to [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php). Here is some help [to choose one](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Comment: You need to clarify. Why not retrieve all records and _do something_ with them along the way?

Comment: @Kleskowy: mysql_fetch_array does retrieve all the records all at once. The way I want them processed is what I described in text...

Comment: @Muur: I completely, understand. My question though pertains to how the data will be processed, not how they're retrieved.

Comment: @JonDavis **WRONG**, mysql_fetch_array retrieves **one** record at a time (_all columns_ from _one record_ are fetched at once). So you can do everything you need while retrieving them one by one.

Comment: Just build an array from the result set and you can do whatever you want with that array (i.e. access record 1, then record 2, then record 1 again, etc.).

Comment: @Kleskowy: I see. Thanks for pointing that out. Can you post code that gets what I want done so that I can feel a little less dumb and get some clarity...

Comment: @JonDavis I did post it, check it out

Answer (score 0):

as you asked - use this code to retrieve all rows from db. Note, that you can mainpulate each row's data on retrieval (I put a comment in the code so you know where to do it), you do not have to wait until after you've retrieved them all.

Also, note that I changed *mysql_** (depracated) to **mysqli_***.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `memberlist` WHERE Active = 1";
$dbLink = mysqli_connect( ); // host, username etc go here - if you haven't connected yet
$res = mysqli_query($dbLink, $sql);

$rowResults = array();
if (mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0) {

  while ($temp = mysqli_fetch_array($res, MYSQL_BOTH)) {

     $dataToProcess = $temp; //store just not to mess with retrieved row data

     //processData, for example - trim title:
     $dataToProcess['title'] = trim($dataToProcess['title']);

     $rowResults[] = $dataToProcess ; // add it to results array

  }
}

var_dump($rowResults); //you now have all the processed results here
```

Answer (score 0):

Here it is. Outer loop increases range of what inner loop loops through.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `memberlist` WHERE Active = 1";

$res = mysql_query($sql);

if (mysql_num_rows($res) > 0) {
  $arr = mysql_fetch_array($res, MYSQL_BOTH);
  for($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
    for($j = 0; $j <= $i; $j++) {
      var_dump($arr[$j]); // 'do somethin' here
    }
  }
}
```